# Convert seconds to human readable time duration

Tags: mysql, time, duration

How would I best convert 90060 (seconds) to a string of "25h 1m"?

Currently I'm doing this in SQL:

```
SELECT 
  IF(
    HOUR(
      sec_to_time(
        sum(time_to_sec(task_records.time_spent))
      )
    ) > 0, 
    CONCAT(
      HOUR(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(task_records.time_spent)))), 
      'h ', 
      MINUTE(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(task_records.time_spent)))),
      'm'
    ), 
    CONCAT(
      MINUTE(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(task_records.time_spent)))),
      'm'
    )
  ) as time
FROM myTable;
```

But I'm not sure it's the most convenient method :-)

I'm open to suggestions on doing this both in SQL (differently than I'm already doing) or in PHP.

EDIT:

Examples of desired strings: "5m", "40m", "1h 35m", "45h" "46h 12m".

Comment: Shouldn't 90060 be `1d 1h 1min` instead of `25h 1min` ?

Comment: No, I need it to be in hours strictly.

Comment: WARNING the accepted answer FAILS for values greater than 3020399 seconds (the max value that SEC_TO_TIME converts correctly).  Maybe the OP's tasks never run longer than 839 hours, but this is definitely not a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(task_records.time_spent),'%Hh %im')
```

Documentation is your friend:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

---

According to comment:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GET_HOUR_MINUTES;
CREATE FUNCTION GET_HOUR_MINUTES(seconds INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(16)

  BEGIN
  DECLARE result VARCHAR(16);
  IF seconds >= 3600 THEN SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%kh %lm');
  ELSE SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%lm');
  RETURN result;
  END

DELIMETER ;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT GET_HOUR_MINUTES(task_records.time_spent) FROM table
```

Comment: How would I omit the preceeding hours part if the time is below 1h? Examples: "5m", "40m", "1h 35m", "45h" "46h 12m"?

Comment: There is no way to do this in one line. If you want to make your queries clean maybe make a routine http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html ?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Didn't tested, but it should work fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5156/discussion-between-henno-and-peter-szymkowski)

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the syntax error problems and the problem that the minute part was actually the hour part.

Comment: @Henno i am really happy to help. And it's quite elegant solution :) Never don't be afraid to use MySQL routines!

Comment: my edit did not make it through peer review process (I don't have 2000 rep yet to edit other people posts directly). Please fix the answer yourself.

Comment: @EXQ Studio, I think the `%Im` in the first SQL statement should use a lowercase i: `%im`.

Comment: this doesn't work for values over 3020399 (the documentation contains a cryptic reference: "The range of the result is constrained to that of the TIME data type. A warning occurs if the argument corresponds to a value outside that range." but I don't see any warning.

Also, that CREATE FUNCTION syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

you can use predefined function sec_to_time()

sec_to_time(number_of_seconds)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time

Comment: This was extremely helpful for me. (Not necessarily answering the question, but very helpful for my situation.) Thanks!

Comment: What does this add that the accepted answer doesn't have?

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME` fails for hour counts in excess of 24 hours (any hour count that does not resolve to a valid clock time). OP's example asked for a readable representation of 25h. This would not work, and would return `[SQLState S1009] Illegal hour value '25'`. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this trick (on MySQL)

```
select date_format("1970-01-01 00:00:00" + interval <value_here> second, "%H:%i:%S")
```

SEC_TO_TIME sometime produces wrong values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

try this: (input your pure seconds time)

```
var hours = Math.floor(input/3600);
var minutes = Math.floor((input-hours*3600)/60);
var seconds = input-(minutes*60)-(hours*3600);
function convertTime(){
return hours":"minutes":"seconds;
}
```

Comment: Um, this is a mysql question not a javascript question.