# Converting year month day to date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My input to the stored procedure is a string (e.g '2 years 3 months 4 days') which is a future date. How to convert this to a date by comparing with current date?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just change the input before going to SQL?

Comment: Sure, string parse is not so simple in SQL server. Read my answer for a PHP solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below Query in SP

```
select dateadd(yy,2,dateadd(m,3,dateadd(d,4,GETDATE())))
                  ^Year       ^Month      ^Days
```

Here is the SP

```
create procedure test1
(
@year INT,
@month INT,
@day INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    select dateadd(yy,@year,dateadd(m,@month,dateadd(d,@day,GETDATE())))
END
```

Comment: He just has a string input though.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @S varchar(50)
set @S = '2 years 3 months 4 days'

select dateadd(day, D.D, dateadd(month, D.M, dateadd(year, D.Y, getdate()))) as TheDate
from (select replace(replace(replace(@S, ' years ', '.'), ' months ', '.'), ' days', '')) as T(S)
  cross apply (
              select cast(parsename(T.S, 1) as int),
                     cast(parsename(T.S, 2) as int),
                     cast(parsename(T.S, 3) as int)Y
              ) as D(D, M, Y)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/8389)

Answer (score -1):

Use `DATEADD`, for example (add one year, to the current data):

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = getdate();
SELECT 'year', DATEADD(year,1,@datetime2)
...
```

So, you should add 2 years, 3 months and 4 days to the current date and then return it as normal date (here I returned future year). Read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms186819.aspx) for details.

Before of the stored procedure invocation you should split the string in a server side language like PHP:

```
$str = '2 years 3 months 4 days';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $data);
```

So `$data[0]=2, $data[1]=3` and `$data[2] = 4`, and so you can invoke @Luv procedure:

```
create procedure test1 -- thanks to Luv
(
@year INT,
@month INT,
@day INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    select dateadd(yy,@year,dateadd(m,@month,dateadd(d,@day,GETDATE())))
END
```

Comment: this wont solve his problem at all - he has some weird "readable time" formatting, using that as input is ... tricky.

Comment: but my input to the parameter is '1 years 1 months 1 days' which is approximately 10/29/2014 (MM/DD/YYYY) from the current date. I need this date to be calculated.

Comment: Do this using DATEADD on the current date is simple as in the example.

Answer (score -4):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
[Convert seconds to human readable time duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193868/convert-seconds-to-human-readable-time-duration)

you may be able to split & convert this formatting into something which is useable via builtin SQL-functions - but i'd recommend using at least a pre-processing scriptlanguage like PHP in order to format the time correctly, PHP "relative" formats may just be the thing, i recall the datetime-class being quite powerful ...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

Comment: PHP parse comes before. The real question IMHO is the SQL part.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense at all - "comes before" is ... just weirdly absurd.