# MySQL: Convert relative seconds count to datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a MySQL database show uptime for devices.  The uptime is how long the device has been up in seconds.  I have a query showing all devices with uptime less than 86400 (24 hours) which I want to bring into a PHP page.

I want to format this uptime string number into a datetime that's human readable.  Here is my query:

```
select hostname,type,uptime from devices where uptime < 86400

And here is sample output:
hostname: serverA
type: server
uptime: 10329
```

How can I turn that 10329 into an actual time?  I assume there is some sort of value that can pull the current time in seconds, minus that uptime value, and convert that into MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS readable value?

Any help is great appreciated!

EDIT:
Decided to use both answer below, but here is the query that fits my needs:

```
SELECT hostname AS Server,type AS Type,NOW() - INTERVAL uptime SECOND AS "Boot Time",last_polled AS "Last SNMP Poll" FROM devices WHERE uptime < 86400
```

Which returns:

```
Server: ServerA
Type: server
Boot Time: 2014-02-11 13:26:52
Last SNMP Poll: 2014-02-11 18:35:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 10329 SECOND
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai.  This was exactly what I was asking for, and can incorporate this into my dashboard.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

`TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(uptime),'%Hh %im')`

Google: [Convert seconds to human readable time duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193868/convert-seconds-to-human-readable-time-duration)

`select hostname,type,TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(uptime),'%Hh %im') from devices where uptime < 86400`

This will give you Hours and minutes of uptime. You can add seconds in as well if you want by reading up on the `TIME_FORMAT` method.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was actually looking to get a startup time from the timestamp.  This is a great answer, and I may consider just using this, but I think Mihai might have provided what I was looking for. Once I have a chance to test this out, I will let you know.  Thanks again for your response!

Comment: This is actually a very bad answer because SEC_TO_TIME maxes out at 3020399 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a time interval to a reference date+time value to compute a new date+time value:

```
SELECT hostname,type,NOW() - INTERVAL uptime SECOND AS "up since"
FROM devices
WHERE uptime < 86400
```