# Display MySQL uptime in days

Tags: mysql

I found this SQL query to display MySQL uptime:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';
```

But I get the value 2059555.

How I can convert it to days?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format MySQL number to datetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713360/format-mysql-number-to-datetime), [Convert seconds to human readable time duration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193868/convert-seconds-to-human-readable-time-duration).

Comment: @cybermonkey: They're not duplicates.  If you disagree, take it up on [meta].

Comment: @eggyal Yes, they are duplicates. The question is essentially 'how do I convert seconds to another value?'; the duplicate targets answer that. Only a small tweak is needed to convert to days (still a duplicate regardless, otherwise we'd have too many questions for one simple thing).

Comment: @cybermonkey: You assume the OP knew the units of the `Uptime` server status variable, which is not something that is indicated in the question—indeed, the question indicates no understanding of how the value should be interpreted.  None of the other questions resolve that problem, or even slightly help to solve it.  EVEN IF the value was known to be seconds, none of those questions help to convert the output of a `SHOW STATUS` command.  So, again, it's not a duplicate.  If you disagree **TAKE IT UP ON [META]**.

Comment: just run "status" in MariDB commandline

Answer (score 34):

On MySQL prompt type this, On the last line we will find Uptime

```
mysql>\s
```

Also if needed to write a query. This will give you in hours and minutes

```
select TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(VARIABLE_VALUE ),'%Hh %im')  as Uptime 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME='Uptime'
```

**Note:** Above version 5.7 use performance_schema instead of information_schema

Comment: One note here, now with MySQL 5.7 this is:

    `select TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(VARIABLE_VALUE ),'%Hh %im')  
    as Uptime 
    from performance_schema.global_status 
    where VARIABLE_NAME='Uptime'`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html

Comment: This won't work if Uptime is > 3020399 because that's the max value that SEC_TO_TIME can convert properly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: On 5.7.23 with an uptime of 159 days, this worked for me `SELECT ROUND(@d:=VARIABLE_VALUE/60/60/24) AS days, ROUND(@d/30.5) AS months FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime';`

Answer (score 8):

With MySQL 5.7+:

```
SELECT
  VARIABLE_VALUE AS Uptime_seconds,
  NOW() AS "Now",
  NOW() - INTERVAL VARIABLE_VALUE SECOND AS "Up since",
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL VARIABLE_VALUE SECOND) AS "Uptime_days"
FROM performance_schema.session_status
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime';
```

Example:

```
+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------+-------------+
| Uptime_seconds | Now                 | Up since                   | Uptime_days |
+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------+-------------+
| 16430228       | 2021-04-09 14:11:58 | 2020-10-01 10:14:50.000000 |         190 |
+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` to find the value for `Uptime`, represented in seconds.  Divide by 86,400 (60 * 60 * 24) to convert to days.

Comment: `select global status ;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'global' in 'field list'`

Comment: its `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` not `select`

Comment: This is actually the answer to the question.

Comment: Well, days may have variable duration depending on timezone, because of daylight saving changes. Use `DATEDIFF` to compute the number of days between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Workbench (as it's free).

Go under the tab `Management > server status`

it will show  Running since: Mon Mar 20 15:29:45 2017 (1 hour)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently for system dashboard. This is what I came up with.
If you have mysql your would remove mariadb with mysqld

```
/usr/bin/systemctl status mariadb | grep Active | cut -f2 -d\; | sed 's/ ago//g'
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.