# MySQL: How to convert seconds to mm:ss format?

Tags: mysql, sql, format

I want to convert seconds to `minute : seconds` format in sql select statement.

At the moment I am using:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(duration) from messages;
```

It works perfectly but it gives me this format of time: `hh:mm:ss` 
but I need `mm:ss`

Is it possible to convert seconds into `mm:ss` format using sql query?

Comment: Do it on client side - much easy(even tiny tiny faster :)). Database is not right tool for this

Comment: Actually I am building a mobile app. So I don't want to put any extra burden on mobile because I am already doing many heavy tasks on client side. So i need to cover such things on server side for good performance on client side ( android app )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the value is less than an hour, then just do:

```
SELECT RIGHT(SEC_TO_TIME(duration), 5) from messages;
```

If you might go over an hour, then do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':', FLOOR(SEC_TO_TIME(duration) / 60),
                 SEC_TO_TIME(duration) % 60)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar project where I needed to convert stored seconds to `m:ss` format.  No matter the amount, there needed to be at least one digit representing minutes and two digits representing seconds.  The hours placeholder was forbidden, so the minutes value could acceptably go beyond `59` and also contain more than 2 digits.  The minute value must not be zero-padded.

This is what I used: ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0e9ad/1))

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(seconds/60), ':', LPAD(MOD(seconds,60), 2, 0)) AS `m:ss`
```

aka

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(seconds/60), ':', LPAD(seconds%60, 2, 0)) AS `m:ss`

seconds  |   m:ss
-----------------
      0  |   0:00
      1  |   0:01
     10  |   0:10
     60  |   1:00
     61  |   1:01
     71  |   1:11
   3599  |  59:59
   3600  |  60:00
   5999  |  99:59
   6000  | 100:00
```

`TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%i:%s')` was unsuitable because the project specifications did not want the minute portion to be zero-padded.  Here is [a good post relating to this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193923/2943403).

There is no single-digit minute option in [TIME_FORMAT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_format.php) or [DATE_FORMAT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/date_format.php).

Comment: Nice solution for variable length min.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0+ you can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) like this to achieve a variable length string similar mickmackusa's answer:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(SEC_TO_TIME(duration), '^(0|:)+', '')
```

Comment: Just, do you have this also to convert hour ?