# Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes, seconds (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic, date-conversion

Example:

> seconds ="1015557";

Result should be:

> 11days 18h:05m:57s

How can do this in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193868/convert-seconds-to-human-readable-time-duration

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Answer (score 11):

```
select concat(
    format(floor(s / @day),0),
    'days ',
    time_format(sec_to_time(s % @day),'%Hh:%im:%ss') 
  ) formatted_date
from (select 1015557 s) t, (select @day = 3600 * 24);
```

produces:

```
+--------------------+                                                                                                                               
| days               |                                                                                                                               
+--------------------+                                                                                                                               
| 11days 18h:05m:57s |                                                                                                                               
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date('1970-12-31 23:59:59')
   + interval 1015557 second,'%j days %Hh:%im:%ss') as result;
```

**sample**

```
mysql>     SELECT
    ->       DATE_FORMAT(date('1970-12-31 23:59:59')
    ->        + interval 1015557 second,'%j days %Hh:%im:%ss') as result;
+----------------------+
| result               |
+----------------------+
| 011 days 18h:05m:57s |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Hello @Bernd, i thank you a lot for this solution. But i found an error with this value:
81865. I get: 365 days 22h:44m:25s - I think that this is an error. Do you have an idea? Here the fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/89478

Answer (score 9):

You can try this out:

```
SET @seconds = 1015557;
SELECT CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H') / 24), 'days ',
            MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H'), 24), 'h:',
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%im:%ss')
        )
AS Result
```

Result should be:

```
11days 18h:05m:57s
```

Hopefully this helps!.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, 
CONCAT( FLOOR(sec/3600),"hour ", FLOOR(MOD(sec,3600)/60),"min",MOD(sec,60),"sec") 
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your answer to put the code preferably in a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [answer] to get some useful tips on answering questions. Esp. the part "fuller explanations are better". Also, you need a very good reason to answer an old, well answered question. Without any explanation in that direction answers like this tend to get deleted in the review process.

Comment: This does not include "days".

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it

Answer (score 1):

If one is interested in fraction of seconds, the following combines the responses from Kent Aguilar and Steven Yang.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H') / 24), 'days ',
  MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@seconds), '%H'), 24), 'h:',
  FLOOR(MOD(@seconds,3600)/60), 'm:',
  MOD(@seconds,60), 's'
) AS Result
```