# mysql function that converts minutes to month,day,hour,minute and second values

Tags: mysql, function, time, minute

I need to use a mysql function that takes as an input a big number that represents the number of minutes and convert it to the number of months, days, hours, minutes and seconds. Can some one help me to make it ?

Comment: The number of minutes... since when? Because "the number of minutes" is usually an integer value between 0 and 59.

Comment: Answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330789/mysql-convert-seconds-to-days-minutes-and-hours) would be helpful.

Comment: @TheImpaler 130 minutes is 2 hours, 10 minutes.

Comment: This sounds like a grade school arithmetic problem. Have you forgotten all the math you learned as a child?

Comment: It's just division and remainders.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but what about months? 28, 29, 30, or 31 days? You need a starting moment in time.

Comment: @TheImpaler True, but that's a different problem from expecting mnutes to be less than 60.

Comment: Consider handling this sort of stuff in application code

Comment: This really sounds like a basic arithmetics question, otherwise the problem needed a better definition - most likely the beginning or end of the interval become important, and defining how to handle leap seconds, is important, and defining if Timezones are relevant or not, etc.