# Converting seconds to time where seconds is greater than 24 hours in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I'm trying to get a real life time based on seconds, where the number of seconds can be greater than 86400 (which equals 24 hours++). So for example;
If the seconds equals 90000 the result will be 25:00:00, but instead I would like the output to be 01:00:00..

My logic is this:

```
IF seconds >= 86400
  // Add day of date +1
  // something similar to SEC_TO_TIME(seconds..). Need some help here
else
  SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modulo:

```
sec_to_time(myvalue % 86400)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c779f2b360faf7d423e1ca0cb77af2d6)**:

```
with t as (select 12 myvalue union all select 9000)
select sec_to_time(myvalue % 86400) v from t
```

```
| v        |
| :------- |
| 00:00:12 |
| 02:30:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41331240/1311977)

```
SELECT
           DATE_FORMAT(date('1970-12-31 23:59:59')
           + interval 86400 second,'%j days %Hh:%im:%ss') as result;
```